# Utilize Hyperlink Mailto function to Bcc address from array

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook

I am trying to bcc multiple emails into 1 utilizing the hyperlink function and mailto hyperlink

The emails are listed in a column together
`=HYPERLINK("mailto:"&C5&"?"&"bcc="&D5:D6&"&subject="&E5&"&body="&F5,"link")`

`&D5:D6&` does not work, I see that `&D5&D6&` does work but would like to input an array as if I have 50 emails, is this possible without using macros?

If there is an alternative to this please advise, the list of emails would ideally be able to dynamically change by changing the emails in the array list

Comment: use `textjoin` on that range. The delimiter should be `";"`